# Dafny: Why does "Math.Max" validate faster than a local "Max"?

Tags: dafny, formal-verification

When I use the standard library `Math.Max` my project validates in seconds.

```
include "../libraries/src/Collections/Sets/Sets.dfy"
import Dafny.Math
```

When I instead copy the function into by own project, validation times out (at 120 seconds).

```
function Max(a: int, b: int): int
{
  if a < b
  then b
  else a
}
```

It seems like it is the same code so how can one way work and the other time out?

[edit: Subset of code: https://github.com/CarlKCarlK/dafnyrepro_sept23/]

Comment: Just a random idea, but can an int be null, or NaN, or something else that isn't comparable?

Comment: It is hard to say anything concrete without looking max in bigger context. Try to provide fixed -randomSeed option to  both ways to see if it is due to randomness. More details about randomSeed is present in  Dafny manual

Comment: Another point to consider is that local functions and lemmas in a dafny file always get evaluated on change, where as library methods are basically treated as axioms and are not re-evaluated.

Comment: I added "{:axiom}" to my the local function Max, but it didn't help.

Comment: You might get an answer from the dev team if you ask in the github discussion forum for the Dafny repo. https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/discussions/

Comment: I now think it is likely a problem with the variability in the validation time. If anyone would like to look, here is a subset of the code: https://github.com/CarlKCarlK/dafnyrepro_sept23/

Tomorrow I'll read and play around with:
 * missing triggers: https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/wiki/FAQ
 * random seeds and the logger: http://dafny.org/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#1365-debugging-variable-verification

I'd, of course, be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Another option is to split verification in multiple batches. I used {:vcs_split_on_every_assert} on SetsEqual and it verified in 30s (Without it, it was timing out in my machine)

Answer (score 0):

With help from Divyanshu Ranjan and others, I learned that Dafny works heuristically via a random search. Changing code superficially (or changing random seeds) can change how much time the search needs. Sometimes, the amount of time changes drastically. If the new time goes beyond a user-set time limit, the validation will fail.

So, you should test the reliability of your validation by trying different random seeds. Here are the commands I used (on Windows) to validate a file with 10 random seeds.

```
@rem Find the location of Dafny and add it to your path
set path=C:\Users\carlk\.vscode-insiders\extensions\dafny-lang.ide-vscode-3.1.2\out\resources\4.2.0\github\dafny;%path%
dafny verify seq_of_sets_example7.dfy --verification-time-limit:30 --cores:20 --log-format csv --boogie -randomSeedIterations:10
```

The result is a *.csv file that you can open as a spreadsheet and then look for failures.

We wrote up our experience in https://towardsdatascience.com/nine-rules-to-formally-validate-rust-algorithms-with-dafny-part-1-5cb8c8a0bb92. See Rule 9 especially.